# @RequestParam different URI

Tags: java, spring

```
@RequestMapping("/recipe/new")
public String newRecipe(Model model){

  model.addAttribute("recipe",new RecipeCommand());
  return "recipe/recipeform";   
}

@PostMapping("recipe")
public String  saveOrUpdate(@ModelAttribute RecipeCommand command){

  RecipeCommand recipeCommand=recipeService.saveRecipeCommand(command);
  return "redirect:/recipe/show/"+recipeCommand.getId();
}
```

I don't understand why in post there is only one proper URI  `@PostMapping("recipe")` and when i try  for example `@PostMapping("/recipe/new")` it doesn't working

I think I don't quite understand rules of writing proper URIs in @Mappings, why is only `@PostMapping("recipe")`  working?'

It's normal controller not rest

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Define _it doesn't working_. What did you expect to happen? Why did you have that expectation? What actually happened?

Comment: I've got 404 error

Comment: and I'm redirected to http://localhost:8080/recipe/

Comment: Note that it's conventional in REST for creating a new recipe to be `POST /recipes`; the "new" is implied with the `POST`. `GET /recipes/new` is a common pattern for displaying a blank HTML form, as here.

Comment: It's not rest controller but I can use

    @RequestMapping(value="/recipe", method=RequestMethod.POST)
but cant value="/recipe/new " and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Spring will consider @RequestMapping URI without `method` property as
>   multiple mappings like `POST: /recipe/new , GET: /recipe/new , PATCH:
>   /recipe/new ..`

Due to above reason `@PostMapping("/recipe/new")` is considered as a duplicate mapping and it will not work.

To solve the problem add the request method property to your `newRecipe` method

```
@RequestMapping("/recipe/new", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newRecipe(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("recipe",new RecipeCommand());
        return "recipe/recipeform";
    }

@PostMapping("/recipe/new")
    public String  saveOrUpdate(@ModelAttribute RecipeCommand command){
       RecipeCommand recipeCommand=recipeService.saveRecipeCommand(command);
       return "redirect:/recipe/show/"+recipeCommand.getId();
    }
```